# Field 'Subject' on Case Kanban View not showing

Tags: case, list-view, kanban, summer-23

When creating a list view for Cases the field 'Subject' is not shown when setting the list view as 'Display as Kanban' but it ís showing when setting it as 'Display as Table'.

This despite setting 'Subject' as one of the first four fields. As seen in the screenshot below 'Subject' is shown in the third line as a visible field. However, on the right it is not actually shown

[image]

Comment: Can you include a screenshot of expected vs actual for better understanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like problem with Salesforce update. Please raise a ticket with Salesforce.

Workaround :
Create a formula field (text) for Subject and add it first 4 display fields. I have tried this today and it worked for me.

Comment: This did indeed turn out to be a bug on the side of Salesforce: https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000tIE6SAAW/case-subject-field-not-showing-in-kanban-view-in-summer-23-release